# Why does Android Studio emulator severely downgrade quality of imageButton to become blurry?

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-xml, android-imagebutton

Please click on image to view what i'm talking about.

[image]

That "Log In" imageButton is a Vector quality image made in xxhdpi. In the xml file that "Log In" imageButton looks great. In the emulator the imageButton, the quality becomes blurry and downgraded. Same thing happens to "testingtesting".

I don't have an android device, will this same thing happen on a device? Is this normal for emulators to do? Should I ignore it or is this a major concern and I should do something?